# Why does SQL not escape/sanitize by default?

Tags: sql-injection

First, since there is no SQL stackexchange I am not sure where the best place to ask this question is (I debated between here and programmers.stackexchange). If this is the wrong place, please move it.

It is an obvious flaw in SQL that inputs are not sanitized by default and user-input can be executed. When designing SQL, surely the programmers must have realized this fact? Why then did they not put any default safeguards against it such as escaping by default, or even better, completely rework it so that user-inputs could never be executed.

Other languages, whether compiled or interpreted, (like Java, Python, C, etc.) don't seem to suffer from a similar vulnerability where user input could be run. Why then is SQL uniquely special in this case?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What do you mean by "SQL inputs are not sanitized" ? When/how should the input be sanitized by SQL?

Comment: It's a hard question, nobody can answer that but the developers itself...a better question might be " why SQL is still used despite its design flaws " or " there are alternatives to SQL who sanitize by default "

Comment: Assuming that by *sanitizing the inputs* you mean not being able to execute them as a command (here: query), SQL has Prepared Statements just for this purpose. Instead of "sanitizing" inputs, they're just sent differently from the query thus disabling them from bring executed as queries themselves.As far as WHY the developers didnt hook this functionality in by default ?, they did. They just left the job of securing the query and making sure that it executes as intended to the application developers

Comment: SQL isn't "uniquely special" in this. In fact, it's not even a flaw in SQL; it's a flaw in the brains of the people who create SQL queries by catenating strings, which really can't be fixed by the people writing standards. Any time a person writes a program on-the-fly by catenating static strings and user data, then runs that program, the potential exists for weird machines. However, a lot of languages offer reflection (e.g. python 2's infamous `input()`, javascript's `eval()`, bash's `eval`), and plenty of people inadequately quote and escape user inputs in their bash scripts.

Comment: Incidentally, every time a bash script fails to put double quotes around a variable which might contain spaces, Zombie Djikstra devours a baby. I see it everywhere, and it's a disgrace.

Comment: SQL needs to store stuff sent to it without corrupting it. Use prepared statements and the issue becomes moot.

Comment: SQL **cannot** sanitize input. It has no idea what should be valid in any given statement.

Comment: For a similar type of bug in C code, think about printf format string vulnerabilities. printf is an interpreter for a little language, and if you feed it a program from an untrusted source, bad things happen. The correct approach, just like in SQL, is to use a fixed program (i.e. constant format string) and add the user data as parameters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SQL is a programming language. The problem is not a lack of SQL about "sanitizing inputs"; SQL is the input, not something that receives inputs.

The problem is applications that take it upon themselves to automatically generate some SQL based on an haphazard mixing of string elements of dubious origin. An application that suffers from a SQL injection vulnerability, is an application that acts as a *code generator*. And automatic code generation is extremely hard to do properly when the target syntax was meant for human consumption -- the generator must be aware of all the arcane details of parsing and avoid all the little details and exceptions that are meant to help humans, but make life very hard for machines.

Nevertheless, when there is a need for executing SQL statements with externally provided parameters, a clean solution exists: it is called [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). SQL databases support, and have supported for long, prepared statements. You cannot blame SQL for "not sanitizing inputs" because SQL offers *exactly* a method for "sanitizing inputs"; you should blame developers for not using it.

(SQL can be blamed for a great number of other things, but not for this one.)

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph of the question you might want to emphasize that the problem of injection is inherent to running generated code - regardless of the language. XSS might serve as another example.

Comment: Another way it could be explained is that by the time the request reaches the SQL parser the information which could be used to distinguish legitimate requests from injection is already gone.